# Script is not working inside AJAX loaded DIV, only html is loaded?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, jquery-events

My JavaScript is not working after ajax response I know that I have to use `$('.ajax-link').on('click', 'a', function (e){`
function for it but when I am using this my `e.preventDefault();` is not working (means whole page is loading instead of ajax call) and if I am using `$('a.ajax-link').click(function (e) {` then ajax is working fine but all script of ajax response page is not working after ajax response. I am using `jquery 1.10`. Below is my whole code:

```
$('a.ajax-link').click(function (e) {
        NProgress.start();
        if (msie) e.which = 1;
        if (e.which != 1 || !$('#is-ajax').prop('checked') || $(this).parent().hasClass('active')) return;
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.sidebar-nav').removeClass('active');
        $('.navbar-toggle').removeClass('active');
        $('#loading').remove();
        $('#dvLoading').show();
        var $clink = $(this);
        History.pushState(null, null, $clink.attr('href'));
        $('ul li.active').removeClass('active');
        $clink.parent('li').addClass('active');
    });

    History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function () { // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
        var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state   



    $.ajax({
        url: State.url,
        success: function (msg) {
           $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(10);
            NProgress.inc();
            $('.main-sec').html($(msg).find('.main-sec').html());
             NProgress.inc();
            setTimeout(function() { NProgress.done(); $('.fade').removeClass('out'); }, 100);
            $('#loading').remove();
            $('.main-sec').fadeIn();
            var newTitle = $(msg).filter('title').text();
            $('title').text(newTitle);
            docReady();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append manually the scripts tag to your document :

```
$.ajax({
    url: State.url,
    success: function (msg) {
      var scripts = $("<div>").html(msg).find( "script");
      scripts.each(function(){
          $('body').append($(this)[0]);
        }
    }
});
```

or you could use the AMD pattern, take a look at requirejs:
http://requirejs.org/

Comment: then try using $.getScript(scriptSRC) if they are not inline

Comment: i am using inline script

Comment: is there any other way or how could i use AMD pattern in my case can you explain more ?

Comment: I edited my response, it works for me, a bit hackish but it works

Comment: RequireJS allows you to organize your code in modules (as in nodejs) and require them when it is needed, or bundle them in a minified js file. it also avoid overriding variables and functions names because all your code is wrapped in functions, it's very useful. But it's a bit tricky to explain if you've never heard of it, read the docs, maybe you could implement it in another future project.